# Convert JSON data to HTML dropdown list with PHP

Tags: php, html, json, xml

How can I convert this XML/JSON data into an HTML `select` droplist using PHP?

**JSON/XML Data:**

```
{"CountryList":"<Countries><Country><Code>AF<\/Code><Name>Afghanistan<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AL<\/Code><Name>Albania<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>DZ<\/Code><Name>Algeria<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AS<\/Code><Name>American Samoa<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AD<\/Code><Name>Andorra<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AO<\/Code><Name>Angola<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AI<\/Code><Name>Anguilla<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AQ<\/Code><Name>Antarctica<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AG<\/Code><Name>Antigua &amp; Barbuda<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AR<\/Code><Name>Argentina<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AM<\/Code><Name>Armenia<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AW<\/Code><Name>Aruba<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AU<\/Code><Name>Australia<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AT<\/Code><Name>Austria<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>AZ<\/Code><Name>Azerbaijan<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>BS<\/Code><Name>Bahamas<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>BH<\/Code><Name>Bahrain<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>BD<\/Code><Name>Bangladesh<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>BB<\/Code><Name>Barbados<\/Name><\/Country><Country><Code>BY<\/Code><Name>Belarus (Belorussia)<\/Name><\/Country><\/Countries>","Error":{"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":""},"Status":1,"TokenId":"bdf0738c-7a47-410e-961a-52da9b5df935"}
```

**Desired HTML output:**

```
<select>
    <option value="AF|Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL|Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ|Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS|American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD|Andorra">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO|Angola">Angola</option>
    <option value="AI|Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="AQ|Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="AG|Antigua & Barbuda">Antigua & Barbuda</option>
    <option value="AR|Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AM|Armenia">Armenia</option>
    <option value="AW|Aruba">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AU|Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="AT|Austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="AZ|Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="BS|Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="BH|Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="BD|Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="BB|Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option value="BY|Belarus (Belorussia)">Belarus (Belorussia)</option
</select>
```

---

**after parsing, am getting array like this**

Array
(
            [CountryList] => AFAfghanistanALAlbaniaDZAlgeriaASAmerican SamoaADAndorraAOAngolaAIAnguillaAQAntarcticaAGAntigua & BarbudaARArgentinaAMArmeniaAWArubaAUAustraliaATAustriaAZAzerbaijanBSBahamasBHBahrainBDBangladeshBBBarbadosBYBelarus (Belorussia)
            [Error] => Array
                        (
                                    [ErrorCode] => 0
                                    [ErrorMessage] => 
                        )
            [Status] => 1
            [TokenId] => 5a5e32c4-77ee-4703-b0b1-4ff275ac61asw0
)

---

**Data that i am getting see in the below link**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9VV_J4sKTatdWJGeHJkOVZzZ00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your data is not XML, is JSON with some tags (custom? I don't know the format) in the 'CountryList' object

Comment: from where come the data? From XML? You can't access to real XML?

Comment: At first glimpse the format looks broken. As if all the opening tags are missing in CountryList.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is - in its current form -  a "please write my code" question

Comment: kindly see i have edited JSON/XML Data: in the post,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one may be it will helpfull for you.

**Solution**

```
$json = json_decode($data);$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->loadXml($json->CountryList);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($source);
$target = new DOMDocument();
$options = $target->appendChild($target->createElement('select'));

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/Countries/Country') as $country) {
    $countryCode = $xpath->evaluate('string(Code)', $country);
    $countryName = $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $country);
    $option = $options->appendChild(
        $target->createElement('option')
    );
    $option->setAttribute('value', $countryCode . "|" . $countryName);
    $option->appendChild($target->createTextNode($countryName));
}

$target->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $target->saveXml($options);
```

**Output:**

```
    <select>
        <option value="AF|Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="AL|Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="DZ|Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="AS|American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="AD|Andorra">Andorra</option>
        <option value="AO|Angola">Angola</option>
        <option value="AI|Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
        <option value="AQ|Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
        <option value="AG|Antigua & Barbuda">Antigua & Barbuda</option>
        <option value="AR|Argentina">Argentina</option>
        <option value="AM|Armenia">Armenia</option>
        <option value="AW|Aruba">Aruba</option>
        <option value="AU|Australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="AT|Austria">Austria</option>
        <option value="AZ|Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
        <option value="BS|Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
        <option value="BH|Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
        <option value="BD|Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="BB|Barbados">Barbados</option>
        <option value="BY|Belarus (Belorussia)">Belarus (Belorussia)</option
     </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data is not XML, it is a JSON string.

If you can access to original XML data, you can obtain better results.

By the way, to decode your current data, use `json_decode`:

```php
$data = json_decode($data);
```

Then, create a pattern that match the countries schema and match all the occurrences in the `$data->CountryList`

```php
$pattern = '{([^>]+)</Code><Name>([^<]+)</Name></Country>}';
preg_match_all($pattern, $data->CountryList, $matches);
```

At this point, you can output your `<option>` list through a `foreach` loop:

```php
foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $val) {
    echo sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $matches[1][$key], $matches[2][$key]);
}
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/9vE0P)**</kbd>

#### Edit: pattern syntax

```
{([^<]+)</Code>([^<]+)</Name></Country>}
 └──┬──┘└──┬──┘└──┬──┘└─┬─────────────┘
    │      │      │     └ 2nd and 3rd tags (not captured)
    │      │      └ One or more chars except ‘<’ (2nd captured group)
    │      └ 1st tag (not captured)
    └ One or more chars except ‘<’ (1st captured group)
```

Comment: Won't it capture "Code>1" and "Name>Something" instead of "1" and "Something?"

Comment: @SparK No. See the demo (note also the rigid string structure and the kind of data, country-code, country-name)

Comment: @SparK it's not XML!

Answer (score 0):

You JSON contains the countries as an XML. So you have to decode the JSON first:

```
$json = json_decode($data);
```

Parse the XML after that:

```
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->loadXml($json->CountryList);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($source);
```

You can use DOM to generate the target XML. Create a target document and append the root node. Iterate the countries using Xpath and create/append the option elements.

```
$target = new DOMDocument();
$options = $target->appendChild($target->createElement('select'));

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/Countries/Country') as $country) {
  $option = $options->appendChild(
    $target->createElement('option')
  );
  $option->setAttribute(
    'value', 
    $xpath->evaluate('string(Code)', $country)
  );
  $option->appendChild(
    $target->createTextNode(
      $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $country)
    )
  );
}

$target->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $target->saveXml($options);
```

Output:

```
<select>
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
  <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
  <option value="AO">Angola</option>
  <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
  ...
```

Comment: it's  not working it is saying.
**Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in.
**Warning:** DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in

Comment: sir need little bit help kindly see again question.